# Creating a dataframe with a logic statement including other dataframes

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I could not find a better title for my issue but the thing is that, let's assume we have a dataframe of film reviews. I want to create another dataframe that includes 1 star or 5 star reviews.

I came with this approach:

```
movie_class = movie[movie['stars'] == 1 | movie['stars'] == 5]
```

However, that gave me an error. But when I create the dataframe with only one condition, the code works fine.

```
movie = movie[movie['stars'] == 1]
```

Could not figure why.

Error:

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-2fe827919d94> in <module>()
----> 1 movie_class = movie[movie['stars'] == 1 | movie['stars'] == 5]

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in __nonzero__(self)
   1119         raise ValueError("The truth value of a {0} is ambiguous. "
   1120                          "Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."
-> 1121                          .format(self.__class__.__name__))
   1122 
   1123     __bool__ = __nonzero__

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Comment: post error message

Comment: Is it with `pandas.DataFrame`?

Comment: yes it is pandas @Arief

Comment: add parens around conditions in the bracket.

Comment: does not change the error @YakymPirozhenko

Comment: `movie_class = movie[(movie['stars'] == 1) | (movie['stars'] == 5)]`

Comment: Okay, movie_class = movie[(yelp['stars'] == 1) | (movie['stars'] == 5)] worked just fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

From what i understand from your question, this example may be what you want to achieve :

Generatung similar dataframe,

```
import pandas
import random

movie = [random.randint(0,5) for i in range(20)];
df = pandas.DataFrame(movie, columns = ['stars']);
```

To classify the 1 star and 5 star boolean independently :

```
one_star_bool = df['stars']==1;
five_star_bool = df['stars']==5;
```

Get the data :

```
one_star = df['stars'][one_star_bool];
five_star = df['stars'][five_star_bool];
```

Of course you can combine these two to get 1 star or 5 stars, but to get it directly you may use :

```
one_or_five = df['stars'][one_star_bool | five_star_bool];
```

Is this okay?

Comment: I see, this may also work the same. But actually one line of code was enough. I just had messed up the parenthesis I guess. `movie_class = movie[(movie['stars'] == 1) | (movie['stars'] == 5)]` This gave me what I wanted.

Comment: @Huzo yes that is enough. This is to be detail, and you actually can have the dataframe with boolean version.